# How do you turn off all cellular communication but leave things like bluetooth and wifi enabled?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, cellular-radio

I'm going to be traveling overseas and don't have an international roaming plan.  I would like to disable my cellular radio while I am there but I'd also like to use bluetooth and wifi.  I don't think I can enable bluetooth or wifi while in airplane mode, though.  How can I do this without physically removing my SIM card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually can enable both of those features while in airplane mode. They get turned off automatically when you first enable airplane mode, but there's nothing that prevents you from re-enabling them:

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right.  I could have sworn I tried this but the ability to re-enable them was disabled.  This must have been on my old phone.  Thanks for the help.